# What do players of mortal PCs do, in practice, with all the MP from Issues?

Tags: chuubos

I know that the only thing a mortal can do with MP is power Afflictions, but Issues are pretty central to playing *Chuubo's Marvelous Wish-Granting Engine* and can potentially generate multiple MP per PC per *session* if the players are really riding them.

At the beginning of a campaign, with brand-new mortal PCs who have Arc 0 powers at best, this seems like a lot of MP to accumulate (and *track!*) for PCs who might have no Afflictions to use them with. Arc 0 mortal PCs could easily go several sessions before ever gaining an Affliction, too.

So I know what MP are *for* in a technical sense, and I'm not asking that. But in actual play practice, what the heck to mortal PCs actually *do* with this ever-expanding pile of MP as the Issues roll through? What do we as players do with it all?

While playing Chuubo's with mortal PCs, do we just… watch our piles of MP add up from 1 or 0 up into the multiples of beginning godlike quantities, until the PCs start acquiring Afflictions to spend them on and then go spend-crazy with the MP? Or is there a source of temporary Afflictions I'm overlooking (like how Wounds come with Bonds) that will naturally absorb this abundance of wishing power? Or do they drain away or reset at some point? Or… this works somehow else?

Answer (score 3):

You're correct in that, if the Afflictions associated with your active or completed Arcs come into opposition to miraculous forces, you can spend MP to fortify the miracles the HG invokes on their behalf. A mortal character's Arc can also potentially take them someplace they can get a miraculous ability.

But, as a GM or as a player it may be tough to envision your Arc taking you somewhere that miraculous. It may also be tough to envision the particular kind of miraculous opposition that might sensibly try to shut down your Affliction. For a more proactive means of spending MP, the Techno Player's Guide introduced the concept of "MP shops", places that anyone, including mortal characters, can invest MP and receive temporary miraculous benefits.

There isn't, like, a sign outside or anything, and you don't necessarily engage in transactions, either. Sure, they can be an actual shop that sells cosplay props with enough patter that you believe they can actually let you do the superhero things. But they can also be your family library that you search for rituals to help you connect to ghosts and the dead, or a community garden you regularly tend and occasionally one of the herbs or flowers just... catches your eye.

The point of an MP shop is that you invest MP and get a one-use miraculous-scale ability, which can include the ability to further spend MP to keep it going, like a ritual which will let you compel one true answer from the dead, or up to two more per dead thing you contact for one more MP each.

Now, you could make a tone argument here, that these things don't really belong outside the Techno genre, which is kind of the anime tie-in video game genre, since they're basically equivalent to the only meaningful ways to spend money in your later Persona series games.

But I think that, no matter what genre you're playing, if you've got a partially or entirely mortal cast that's going to stay that way, you can still come up with an appropriate conduit to the miraculous.

Comment: How serendipitous! Just as I was finishing up my own self-answer (since I've discovered some misconceptions in the question), I see another answer come in. How unlikely is that timing. :) Thanks for the additional info — that does give me ideas. And I do think that the right characters and story could see things like “MP shops” even in a Pastoral game!

Comment: I've rewritten this slightly due to some confusion on my part, where I misread the arc powers for miraculous arcs as afflictions, but I'm glad it's been of use.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be partly down to a misreading of the rules.

Miraculous characters don't necessarily have Bonds and Afflictions, but mortal characters necessarily start with a mortal Arc, and mortal Arcs *do* come with Bonds and Afflictions. After character creation, each mortal PC will have one Bond (at level 2) and one Affliction (at 1 + the level of the Arc it comes from).

So there's always an Affliction around for a mortal PC to spend their MP on. Notably though, an Affliction coming into play doesn't always mean MP can be spent — the MP spend is for Strike on any miracles that the Affliction requires to enforce its *true*-ness, but Afflictions don't always or even often need to cause miracles. They can often just be true, without making the impossible happen. Afflictions won't always be able to absorb the MP floating around then.

However, multiple MP can be spent on Strike at a time, so even if a bunch of it accumulates, that's okay — it just means that there's going to be a lot of wishing power to bolster miracles caused by Afflictions against other miracles that try to overrule them, when an Affliction actually does need a miracle to enforce itself.

So yes, there's still going to be accumulating piles of MP, and maybe a particular PC just never sees the need to spend any. I guess just let them accumulate. Perhaps that gently upwards-ticking number will inspire the player to take the PC on an Arc or Quest that *does* give them something to spend it on…